# How to split comma delimited values?

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, csv

I have code to import multiple text files into Excel with each file in a new column.

The imported values in each column are comma separated and I want to modify the code to separate the comma-delimited values into adjacent columns.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughTextFiles()
    ' Defines variables
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Textline As String
    Dim Result() As String
    Dim DisplayText As String
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    ' Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Defines LastCol as the last column of data based on row 1
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Sets the folder containing the text files
    myPath = "C:\Users\ashra_ua\OneDrive - Stichting Deltares\Desktop\Excel2" & "\"
    
    ' Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.txt"
    
    ' Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    
    ' Loop through each text file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        ' Sets variable "RowCount" To 1
        RowCount = 1
        ' Sets variable "Text" as blank
        Text = ""
        ' Set variable equal to opened text file
        Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
        ' Do until the last line of the text file
        Do Until EOF(1)
            ' Add each line of the text file to variable "Text"
            Line Input #1, Textline
            Text = Textline
            ' Update RowCount row of the current last column with the content of variable "Text"
            Cells(RowCount, LastCol).Value = Text
            ' Increase RowCount by 1
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Loop
        ' Close the text file
        Close #1
        ' Splitting the results
        Result = Split(Text, ",")
        For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
        DisplayText = DisplayText & Result(i)
        Next i
        ' Increase LastCol by 1 to account for the new data
        LastCol = LastCol + 2
        ' Get next text file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    ResetSettings:
    ' Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"
    
End Sub
```

This code imports all the text files and then adds a blank column next to each column which I want to use for separating the values.

Additionally, after separating the values, I want to delete all the odd numbered columns.

Comment: Does your text files have only one row? Otherwise,  `Result = Split(Text, ",")` after `Close #1` will only process the last text row. Is it done only for learning scope? I do not see being of any use in your code `DisplayText`)...

Comment: No. My text files have a lot of rows. You can see in the first loop there is a RowCount = RowCount + 1 which reads all the rows one by one and write them. I want to separate all the values in each column. 

It is not just for learning. I have to extract only specific data from the text files. And for that I have to import all of them into excel and then because values by default are comma-separated so I want to have them into separate columns and then delete the odd numbered columns because they are the same in each text file. I do not need them.

Comment: I could see `RowCount`, but it could be used only for the next text file to be processed... Then, you must split the text inside the loop and put the resulted array directly in cells of `RowCount` row.

Comment: I am not importing each text file into new row. Each text file is being imported in a new column. For that the loop with LastCol = LastCol + 2 is being used.

Comment: I understood that, but I thought you do it by mistake... Then, if you import each file in a new column, what do you finally want to accomplish? You practically ask for support in deleting half or the imported files (odd columns...). How many items are in each row, separated by comma?

Comment: There are only 2 items in each rows to be separated.

Comment: At first, I want to separate them into columns. And after that I want to delete every odd numbered column. 
But first goal is to just separate the csv values into new column for all the rows and for all the text files being improted.

Comment: OK. Understood, now (I think...). Even if I believe that you can load only the necessary value from the comma separated string... So, if you want to delete the odd columns, it is enough to fill the empty column with the second element of comma separated row. Then I can prepare a piece of code able do delete the columns keeping the original text files lines... Is my understanding correct, now? Is what you want keeping from the comma separated string, the second one?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to keep the second element of comma separated string for all the rows (in one text file which is in one column) and for all the columns (i.e. all imported text files).
But the issue is, I am unable to separate the values i.e. unable to fill the empty column with second element of comma separated row. So therefore, I asked help for that first and later deleting the odd numbered columns.

Comment: Try please, replacing your loop with the one I posted and then, comment all the code lines after it (maybe, except ResetSettings: and what follows after it). If I understood well which is your need, it should return exactly what you need, without any need of columns deletion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next simplified loop. It should be doing what you need, without being necessary to delete any columns. Nothing after the loop must be kept from your code:

```
Do While myFile <> ""
    RowCount = 1
    Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
        ' Do until the last line of the text file
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, Textline
            If UBound(Split(Textline, ",")) = 0 Then
                cells(RowCount, LastCol).Value = Textline
            Else
                cells(RowCount, LastCol).Value = Split(Textline, ",")(1)
            End If
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Loop
    Close #1

    LastCol = LastCol + 1
    myFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: It gives me an error in the line cells(RowCount, LastCol).Value = Split(Textline, ",")(1)

I have sent you a folder containing text files on your email. Could you kindly check it on your own PC and let me know if it works for you. Also you can have a look at the files I am trying to work with.

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf : The best idea is that **you** understand what is it about... So, try inserting in front of the problematic line, the next one: `Debug.print IsArray( Split(Textline, ",")`. If it returns `True`, try put another line: `Debug.Print Split(Textline, ",")(1)`. Your text files, maybe have empty rows (at least one at the end) and if so, we must adapt the code to handle the situation...

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf : the first text file (in alphabetic order - 'conc_1.000000_1.000000_|10.txt') has in the first two rows 366 followed by 2. Will this type of record be kept? For such a row, of course, the code cannot split anything by comma and returns an error. But the good news is we can overpass it, **if we know what we want**... So, what to be done which such records. If they should be skipped, this is simple. If not, please, specify what is to be done.

Comment: It gives the same error that subscript out of range. I tried this Debug option but it stays the same. Out of range error.

Comment: We do not need the first four rows actually. We can skip them

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf: OK. I will firstly adapt the code to also copy all those rows, maybe they are a kind of header... You will see that it would be extremely easy to comment a code line...

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf: Adapted. Please, check it in this variant. Finally, if you do  not need the first two rows, you can comment the line `cells(RowCount, LastCol).Value = Textline` and move `RowCount = RowCount + 1` before `End If`. I was referring to the first two rows (without comma), In order to skip the first four you should condition by `If RowCount > 4 Then ... the Loop code ... End If`.

Comment: I am sorry but which variant are you referring here?

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf: Did you refresh the page (this one...)?

Comment: Yes I did. Did you share any code? Because I did not receive any code. You asked me to check in the adapted variant. But I didn't receive it.

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Ashraf: Where from to receive it? I am referring to the above code. I edited and adapted it... This is how our community works.

Comment: Ahh yes. My bad. You edited the above code. I didn't realize that. And yes, I get it now. It is working exactly how I want it.